# How to properly use merge map in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two observables, each of them call an API to get a result. The second observable need the result of the first to call the API. So, like it's recommended on that tutorial https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs , I have writed this :

```
export class EditVarianteComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentVariante: Variante;
  public url: string;
  public value$ : Observable<{}>;
  constructor(private router:Router, private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, private varService:VarianteService, private famService : FamillesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.url = atob(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id);

    this.value$ = this.varService.getResource(this.url).pipe(
      mergeMap(variante => this.famService.getFamilleById(variante.id_famille))
    );

    this.value$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

  }
```

But, it always return me that variante.id_famille is undefined. Does anybody know why there is this bug ?

Comment: well does `variante` have a property `id_famille` and is it something else than `undefined`?

Comment: yes, for example if I do this : this.varService.getResource(this.url).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
    );
That is what it's returned :
id: 1
idFamille: 1
nom: "E2"

Comment: well then you should use that... i.e `this.famService.getFamilleById(variante.idFamille)`, not `id_famille`... `id_famille` is correctly `undefined` as it does not exist in your data.

Comment: thank you so much, it works now.